# Limit proof for a function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Regarding: If there exists an $L∈R$ such that $lim_{x→a}f(x)=L$ for every $a∈R$, then $f(x)=L$ for every $x∈R$

I would like to make a counter-example for the question.

I chose a function, and want to show that it has a Limit:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}L&x\ne a\\L/2 &x=a\end{cases}$

I started with:

Let $ϵ>0$. We choose $δ= $

Let $x$ such that $0<|x−a|<δ $

So $|f(x)-L|< $

I don't know how to chose δ.

I am looking for something like $|a-x|/2$ , but I am a bit confused...

Any help will be awesome!

Comment: @Bungo Yes it is a counter example, sorry I will fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|x-a|>0$ you know $x\neq a$, hence $f(x)=L$. Thus $|f(x)-L|=0<\epsilon$.

In summary, any choice of $\delta$ is sufficient.

Edit: As Bungo pointed out, this is just the first part of proving the counterexample. You need also to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=L$ for every $b\in\mathbb R$, not just the special case $b=a$. I believe $\delta=|b-a|$ should work.

Comment: How can any choice of $\delta$ be sufficient? If evaluating the limit at, say, $x=b$, then $\delta$ needs to be smaller than $|b-a|$ in order to yield $|f(x) - L| = 0$.

Comment: Ah, maybe you're referring only to the $b=a$ case.. The OP is confusing himself/herself by reusing $a$ to refer to a specific point whereas the question requires the limit to hold for all $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Alright mate! Thank you! So how do I implement this? Why because $f(x)=L$, it means that $|f(x)-L|<ϵ $?

Comment: @Bungo I believe OP is taking the limit at $x=a$ specifically as a counterexample.

Comment: @Math4me If $f(x)=L$ then of course the distance between them $|f(x)-L|$ is zero right? Then $0<\epsilon$ so you are done.

Comment: @M.Nestor Right, but he/she needs to show that this function satisfies $\lim_{x \to b} f(x) = L$ for all $b$, not just a single point $b=a$.

Comment: @Bungo Yes that's the point

Comment: @Bungo Very true, so the counterexample is not complete. I expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and this is my misunderstanding here, how did you choose $δ$ to be $δ=min{ϵ,|b−a|}$ ?

Comment: @Math4me Without going into full details, such a choice guarantees that the interval $(b-\delta,b+\delta)$ *never* contains the point $a$. I recommend trying to prove it!

Comment: So, I need to separate this into: 1. $0<|x-a|$ and 2. $|x-a|<δ$? Is that correct?

Comment: FYI, I think you can just take $\delta = |b-a|$ instead of $\delta = \min\{\epsilon, |b-a|\}$.

Comment: @Bungo I understand that, but I can't take $δ$ to be equal to something who I didn't define before... About $b$, do I need to first write $Let$ $b \in R$, and explain what is $b$?

Comment: @Math4me Well, the original question said "for every $a \in \mathbb R$", but then you re-used $a$ to refer to a specific point in your counterexample. So my $b$ is a replacement for the $a$ in the original question. If you would use a different letter in your counterexample, then $a$ would retain its original meaning.